# How to connect to an android device from a webserver?

Tags: android, connection, webserver, connect

I'll be having a webserver which needs to get data from an android device. So the webserver has to send a command to the android device, which leads into triggering a method in the app.
But I don't want to have a continuous socket connection because the call may only happen like once a month.
What technic could I use to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can probably solve this by using a push notification

Answer (score 0):

You can send a push notification to your device. Once received, you can start sending data. This is probably the best approach, because it is initiated by the webserver only when the data is needed.

Alternatively if the interval at which you require the data to be sent is somewhat constant, you could poll the webserver from your app to check if the data is required at that time and if so, proceed to send your data. This approach puts the workload on the app.

Comment: Thank you! So you can send push notifications from a websever which triggers a certain method inside the app?

Comment: Yes, you can send a push notification and handle it however you want in your app.